# Django group permissions for whole app

Tags: python, django, permissions

Can I give a group all permissions for a whole application programmatically?
Of course I could give the group all add,change,delete permissions for every specific model in the application. But later, if I need to add another model, I need to change the code, where I give the permissions, too.
So I need find a possibility to grant all permissions too all models inside an app, without knowing their names.
The Django documentation doesn't help me with that.

**Edit**
To give you a bit more details: I sublcassed the RemoteUserBackend and overrode the configure_user method to add a new user to a specific group. If this group isn't created, I create it and want to give it the necessary permissions:

```
class MyRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):

    def configure_user(self, user):
        group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="mygroup")
        if created:
            pass
            # Give permissions here

        user.groups.add(group)

        group.save()
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way using the default permission system

Comment: The only thing that comes into my mind is to write a middleware which checks if the request path matches the application, and then check for user permissions. It's a rather fuzzy way, however.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to get all classnames of a module? then I could do someting like `for classname in module: classname.addpermission...`

Comment: You could create sub-views for the admin... Though that's kinda complicated and might be overkill..

Comment: You can write management command, which would sync permissions of group with certain app.

Comment: @GillBates That's tedious, though, ain't it? I mean, you still need to run a command every time you add something...

Comment: @yuvi Well, anyway you need to run a command when you adding models to sync DB. Otherwise - you will need to sync permissions at every request - and this will add overhead.

Comment: @GillBates That's my point. Since Permission objects are saved to the database, you can't have them as a dynamic calculated object, so there's no solution other then using a different permission system entirely.

Comment: @GillBates I did, and I understand how permissions work in django. My point it that you're still doing *something*, when a perfect solution would allow to set a group of users as administrators for everything within a ceratin app without having to reconfigure this every time (even if reconfiguring is as simple as running a manage command)

Answer (score 2):

This is quick sketch of management command that syncs app models permissions with group:

```
# coding=utf-8

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, Group

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<group_name app_label>'
    help = ('Syncs permissions of group with given name with permissions 
             of all models of app with giver app_label ')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        group_name= args[0]
        app_label = args[1]

        group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
        cts = ContentType.objects.filter(app_label=app_label)
        perms = Permission.objects.filter(content_type__in=cts)
        group.permissions.add(*perms)
```

Comment: Won't I have here still the problem to get all models in the module?

Comment: Don't see any problem - `app_label` identify certain app, all models of this app has corresponding `ContentType` objects in DB, so getting all permissions for theese content types means getting all permissions for all models for the app.

Comment: Ah okay. I haven't heard about ContentType...I'll read about it

Answer (score 0):

You could make the users of the group superusers, then when you check permissions, do:

```
if user.is_superuser:
    #allow
else:
    #check permissions
```

Comment: No...I really don't want to make my users superusers. If I did, I  won't need a permission system anymore

Answer (score 0):

```py
class MyRemoteUserBackend(RemoteUserBackend):
    def configure_user(self, user: User, request: HttpRequest, created: bool) -> User:
        """Allow all users to administer all models through the admin site"""
        group, _ = Group.objects.get_or_create(name="mygroup")
        # Always update in case there are new models
        group.permissions.add(*Permission.objects.all())
        user.groups.add(group)
        user.is_staff = True
        return user
```

A variation that I'm currently using is to replace `.all()` with `filter(codename__startswith="view")` for read-only access as the baseline.