# How to handle users and roles by app in Django

Tags: django, web, python-3.5

Hello everyone let me ask something about the admin interface and how can I handle my users by app.

Well so sorry I'm nooby first of all. So, I need to create a new app for basically take some quiz so I will need users and these users within my app should have a different role as a student or teacher and so on.

The thing is that I don't know if the admin Django interface is just for the DB models or whether I can use it as a security layer in my app.

Or otherwise, I should create a buck of tables in my app model for users and roles and then handle everything from the model because the admin is just the DB access.  what could you tell me? thanks﻿ so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django group permissions for whole app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039558/django-group-permissions-for-whole-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django's documentation about Django admin - [Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

> model-centric interface where trusted users can manage content on your site.

Django comes with a [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User), you can extend it to represent teachers and students as described in django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model), you would create [ModelAdmins and register your models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects). Beyond that you can manage your users easily through the admin system, example code:

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Teacher(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teacher')


class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='student')
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Teacher, Student


admin.site.register(Teacher)
admin.site.register(Student)
```

As for security, it is not clear what you mean by "use it as a security layer in my app", if you elaborate more, people can better help you. You can generally learn about security in django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/security/).