# Django user model

Tags: django, python-3.x, web

I have a Django app where I have extended the user model. (see below). I have one type of user that has 3 properties - email, full_name and an avatar. I am going to be having multiple types of users. Maybe Teachers, Students, Parents, Alumni, etc (not my field, but an example). Should I put fields that they all have in common in this below User model and then create a model that has properties that the 4 don't share (e.g. grade you teach, or year in school, year graduated? I'm making this up on the fly, but you see what I mean)  with a foreign key to join them. I'm trying to extend [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49576851/how-to-handle-users-and-roles-by-app-in-django) . I'm not sure what the related_name arg means.

```
    class Teach(AbstractBaseUser):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teacher')
        classes = models.EmailField(...)
        year_started_teaching = models..

    class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teacher')
        year_graduating = models.Integer()

   class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        avatar      = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True)
        is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login 
        staff       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user non superuser
        admin       = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser 
        timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Or should I have 4 separate models that each have the users in it. At some point, I'll have a list of all users that I want to filter by and so I think having the main model and the model.

```
class Teach(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, 
    classes = models.EmailField(...)
    year_started_teaching = models..

class Student(AbstractBaseUser):
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)          
    year_graduating = models.Integer(...)
```

I'm pretty sure I shouldn't have just one model with flags to denote user types.

Comment: I think the second option is much better. And you can connect with Student and Teacher with a `M2M` relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only a single user model inherited from AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser. I believe in your case it`s a better option to use OneToOne relation. For example:

```
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):
    """ shared extra fields for all users """
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name   = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True) 

class Student(models.Model):
   profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   year_graduating = models.Integer(...)

class Teacher(models.Model):
   profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile,
         on_delete=models.CASCADE,
   )
   year_started_teaching = models.Integer(...)
```

And in your settigs.py:

```
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Profile'
```

As you can see AUTH_USER_MODEL - supposed to be a single model, thats why it's a bad idea to have several models inherited from AbstractBaseUser. Otherwise creating user authentication system will become a huge headache. The only drawback - is it would be possible to have user of both types - Teacher and Student, but for my point of view it`s not a big deal and very easy to check.

Another option is to use Generic relations:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

But it`ll  make more difficult to manage in your code base.